# Random Access Into ROS Bag File

Tags: ros

Is there a way to open a ROS bag file (using python or C++) and then randomly shuffle through the file (i.e. I'd like a seek-like function to jump to the n-th sample of a topic in constant time)? I expect large bag files, so pre-loading the bag file is not an option.

[What I found so far](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API) only lets me iterate over the messages in an ordered fashion.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [rosbag::View](http://docs.ros.org/en/diamondback/api/rosbag/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1View.html) is created and should be used for. Check out the [Cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) for some simple samples.

You can simply query by [topic](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1TopicQuery.html) or [type](https://docs.ros.org/en/api/rosbag_storage/html/c++/classrosbag_1_1TypeQuery.html). Also the constructor of the view, allows to define start and end times. This way you should be able to access the bag file in a very generic way.

As an alternative, you may could think about creating dedicated bag files before you are going to analyze them:

- Filter topic of bag files using rosbag filter like [described here](https://answers.ros.org/question/238225/extract-a-topic-from-bag-file-and-save-it-to-another-bag-file/)
- Split bag files by time at recording them with [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Commandline)
- Split bag files by time using rosbag filter like [described here](https://answers.ros.org/question/99711/how-to-split-a-recorded-rosbag-file/)

Comment: Thanks @Fruchtzwerg for the quick answer. I also stumbled over the rosbag::View. However, I don't see a way to *randomly* shuffle through the bag, i.e., jump to the 47th sample of a topic. Would the following work? Run through the bag, collect all timestamps, generate one view for each time stamp, then use these to read a specific sample? <- Also, would each access take constant time to read or would this result in quadratic complexity overall? Also: Since I want to shuffle through the bag multiple times, I don't want to rewrite the bag each time.

Comment: I don't think thats a very performant way. Maybe it's really the best just to iterate over all messages, pick them randomly. Since you are not instanciating the messages itself, they are not loaded to memory with their content anyway until you access their content.